# Closing Firefox Browser Entirely Via Javascript & Plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am using a portable version of firefox in a kiosk mode for a game I am developing. The idea is that presentation layer of the game is down using javascript & svg in a browser, but it needs an exe to run it. When you run the portable firefox exe, it starts up fullscreen, no buttons or toolbars and automatically loads my index page; which is perfect. But at the moment, when a user wants to end the game they need to hit Alt+F4.

From looking around, I get the impression it is not possible to use javascript alone to close the browser. But since the firefox version and plugins are mine to control, if I could find/make a plugin that would listen to some javscript event and close the entire browser when requested - job done. Any ideas how to go about this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows to tue in about:config, that will allow you to use window.close() function to close the window.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, finally got around to testing this. It works perfectly, thank you kindly.